# Attribute Summary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here's my code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EncryptAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If you use this attribute, database attribute size must be caclulated as such: 
    /// dbAttributeSize = (Math.Floor(fieldLength / 16) + 1) * 32
    /// </summary>
    public EncryptAttribute()
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, there's a formula that I would like displayed to the user within VisualStudio's Intellisense if the user chooses to use the `Encrypt` attrbute.

However, the summary doesn't appear.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the `summary` needs applied to the class.

Comment: Are you getting compilation errors? Are you sure your class's build action is set to Compile?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the summary at the class level, instead of the constructor level.

```
/// <summary>
/// If you use this attribute, database attribute size must be calculated as such: 
/// dbAttributeSize = (Math.Floor(fieldLength / 16) + 1) * 32
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EncryptAttribute : Attribute
{
    public EncryptAttribute()
    {    
    }
}
```

Also, you misspelled `caclulated`, should be `calculated`.

Comment: i tried that too, but it didn't work.  That's what I tried originally. It just shows the full class/namespace path.

Comment: @spdev Try closing and re-opening Visual Studio. Update your question with the Visual Studio version. By the way, tried your code in VS 2013 and it worked for me.

Comment: Also try going to `Build\Clean` in the menu if restarting doesn't work. Putting attributes on the class should work.

Comment: Using VS 2014 Update 4.  Tried build/clean as well.